# Unable to get address google maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to get address using lat ,lng .
But its not working pasting the code below.
I really appreciate any help.
I am getting exception all the time and not the value whats the mistake?

Thanks in Advance.

```
       googleMap.setOnMapClickListener((OnMapClickListener) new OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                  final LatLng pt = point;

                  marker2 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                  .position(pt)
                  .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));



                    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                            MainActivity.this,
                            "Searching Location....", "Please wait....");


                    new Thread(new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            try {




                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), GeocoderUtil.getAddress(marker2.getPosition(), MainActivity.this), 5).show();


                                }catch(Exception e)
                                {


                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {

                                            progressDialog.dismiss(); 

                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"error.", 5).show();
                                        }
                                    });


                                }}}

                    ).start();
```

Exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.maps.maps.MainActivity$1.onMapClick(MainActivity.java:442)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$.onMapClick(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.h$a.onTransact(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:297)
    at bor.a(SourceFile:93)
    at maps.af.q.b(Unknown Source)
    at maps.ap.bo.b(Unknown Source)
    at maps.ap.bk.onSingleTapConfirmed(Unknown Source)
    at maps.bt.g.onSingleTapConfirmed(Unknown Source)
    at maps.bt.i.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Whether you are using google marker and if user clicks on marker you want to get address?

Comment: yes .I am using maponclickListener which gets lat/lng correctly but when I tried  the code above it goes over it and its not processed .I tried to debug it but the statement including geocoder and the rest of the code is skipped.Please tell me how to make it work ?Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you are getting lat long value than just write List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(latitude ,longitude , 1);
           if (addresses.size() > 0) 
              {
              for (int index = 0; 
              index < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); index++)
               address += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(index) + " "; } for getting the address for perticular lat long value..

Comment: Hi Subhalaxmi and what should variable geoCoder look like ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Follow this code to get address:

```
            final TextView address = (TextView) infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.Address);
        address.setText(GeoCoderUtil.getAddress(marker.getPosition(), CurrentActivity.this));

    GeoCoderUtil.java:


    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.location.Address;
    import android.location.Geocoder;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

    public class GeoCoderUtil {

        public static String getAddress(LatLng latLng, Context context) {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context);
            double latitude = latLng.latitude;
            double longitude = latLng.longitude;

            String address = "";

            try {
    Log.i("Address Info","Address based opn geocoder");
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,
                        longitude, 1);

                if (addresses != null && !addresses.isEmpty()) {
                    Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                    StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder();
                    int addressLineIndex = returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex();

                    int addressLinesToShow = 2;
    //              To get address in limited lines
                    if (addressLineIndex < 2) {
                        addressLinesToShow = addressLineIndex;
                    }
                    for (int p = 0; p < addressLinesToShow; p++) {
                        strReturnedAddress
                                .append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(p)).append(
                                        "\n");
                    }
                    address = strReturnedAddress.toString();
                } else {
                    address = "Address not available";

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                address = "Address not available";
                Log.e("Address not found","Unable to get Address in info window");
            }
            return address;
        }

        public static String getDistanceByUnit(double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude) {
            float[] distance = new float[1];
            Log.i("Distance","Distance from source to end");
            Location.distanceBetween(startLatitude, startLongitude, endLatitude,
                    endLongitude, distance);
            String distanceByUnit = "Not Available";

            DecimalFormat d = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
            if (distance[0] > 999.99) {
                distance[0] = distance[0] / 1000;
                distanceByUnit = String.valueOf(d.format(distance[0])) + " Km";
            } else {
                distanceByUnit = String.valueOf(d.format(distance[0])) + " m";
            }
            return distanceByUnit;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi SHylu.I tried your code I am getting exception .I have updated my code above please check it out and let me know where ist he problems .Thanks again.

Comment: Which exception you are getting let me know.

Comment: getting exception in list<Address> line  . Updated my code .Please have a look.

Answer (score 10):

ADDRESS::FROM LAT N LONG IN MAP V2:

```
    String address = "";
     Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder( getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
         try {
           List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(latitude ,longitude , 1);
           if (addresses.size() > 0) 
              {
              for (int index = 0; 
              index < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); index++)
               address += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(index) + " "; }
                           }
         catch (IOException e) {        
             e.printStackTrace();
           }   
 googleMap_v2.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
          current_location.setText("Latitude:" +  latitude  + ", Longitude:"+ longitude );
          current_address.setText("current Address :" + address ); 
          googleMap_v2.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("current status")); 
        }}
```

Comment: gtting exception in List<Address> line.Updated my code please have a look.Thanks again,

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

Geocoder coder;

```
    public String PointToLoc(LatLng pos )
{
String address="";
try {

List<Address>addresses=coder.getFromLocation(pos.latitude,pos.longitude,1);

if (addresses.size()>0)
{

for (int index=0;index<addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex();index++)

            address += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(index)+"";

        Log.d("Address",""+ address); //full address
        Log.d("Address1",""+  addresses.get(0).getLocality()); //city
        Log.d("Address2",""+  addresses.get(0).getSubLocality()); //area

     }


    }
 catch (IOException e)
        {        
          e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    return address;
}
    @Override
  public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
  String cur_address=PointToLoc(marker.getPosition());
  //Toast the above string.You will get it.

    }
```

Comment: I used   Geocoder coder =new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());  for coder variable you mentioned above but I got service is unavailable .I check the document for mapsv2 .apparently geocoder is not supported .What is the work around ??  Thanks again for looking into the question

Comment: declare it inside try statement

Comment: Tried that but says service not available thinking of using Google Geocoding API!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 // An AsyncTask class for accessing the GeoCoding Web Service
    private class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>>{

        @Override
        protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
            // Creating an instance of Geocoder class
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
            List<Address> addresses = null;

            try {
                // Getting a maximum of 3 Address that matches the input text
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0], 3);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return addresses;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addresses) {

            if(addresses==null || addresses.size()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            // Clears all the existing markers on the map
            googleMap.clear();

            // Adding Markers on Google Map for each matching address
            for(int i=0;i<addresses.size();i++){

                Address address = (Address) addresses.get(i);

                // Creating an instance of GeoPoint, to display in Google Map
                latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());

                String addressText = String.format("%s, %s",
                address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                address.getCountryName());

                markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                markerOptions.title(addressText);

                googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                // Locate the first location
                if(i==0)
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            }
        }
```